# How Embedly Oembed picks the description of the Resource?

Tags: embedly

I tried to extract the resource(page details with URL) with Embedly Oembed API https://embed.ly/docs/explore/oembed. But Description value varies for different pages.
Document says that

```
The description of the resource. It's picked in the following order:

The oEmbed description
The open graph description
The meta description tag
An excerpt pulled programmatically by Embedly
```

I tried a few URLs with meta: description value set, But still, oembed API returns some other text in the page which does not closely describe the page.

Could someone please give me the details to oembed API description field extraction?